# How I can get dynamically 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 etc., using for loop in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm using C# and I Need to generate 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 etc. numbers using for loop.

Actual result :

**how to make output** =1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 etc., number.

```
           int num1 = 34;
            int prevNumber = 0;
            int nextNumber = 0;
            int orderno = 0;
            bool identity=false;
            for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    string Even = i.ToString();
                    if (!identity)
                    {
                        orderno = prevNumber;
                        nextNumber = i;
                        identity = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        orderno = prevNumber;
                        identity = false;
                        //nextNumber = i;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string odd = i.ToString();
                    if (identity)
                    {
                        orderno = nextNumber;
                        nextNumber = i;
                        prevNumber = orderno;
                        identity = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (nextNumber == 0) orderno = i;
                        else orderno = nextNumber;
                        prevNumber = orderno;
                    }
                }
                txt_number.Text += " " + orderno.ToString();
            }
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

EXPECT OUTPUT
[image]

Comment: Just loop from 1-x and output each number twice?  I don't see what *this much code* is trying to accomplish for the expected output...

Comment: Assuming that `num1` is the upper limits, then divide it by two and loop that many times. Print the value for that loop *twice*.

Comment: check the output of `for (int i = 1; i <= num1; i++) Console.Out.Write((i + 1) / 2 + " ");`

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems overly complicated. You can just print/ append the same number twice. If you want a single `Console.WriteLine()` and do it efficiently you should also use a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-8.0) to avoid creating `string`s on the heap all the time (since `string`s are immutable and have to be garbage collected).

If your input is the number of numbers to output (or something like this) you need to divide your input by 2 in order to get upper bound for the numbers to generate. Then you'd just have to decide what should happen in the event of an edge case where the input is odd. If you can at max output the upper bound amount of numbers and you must always duplicate the number then you have to floor the division by two (which automatically happens when you do integer division).

If on the other hand you want to ceil the division you can do so by adding `1` to the result of the integer division.

> Obviously you could also use the BCL functions `Math.Floor()` and `Math.Ceil()` but that's not necessary here.

So your code could look like this:

```cs
using System.Text;

namespace MyProgram;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myInput = 35;
        var upperBoundFloor = myInput / 2;        // if you want to input up until 17 for an input of 35  
        var upperBoundCeil = (myInput / 2) + 1;   // if you want to output up until 18 for an input of 35
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= myInput; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(i);
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(i);
            sb.Append(" "); // if you don not want a trailing " " you need to check for the last iteration here
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Using upperBoundFloor: \n{DuplicateNumbers(upperBoundFloor)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Using upperBoundCeil: \n{DuplicateNumbers(upperBoundCeil)}");
    }

    public static string DuplicateNumbers(int upperBound)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= upperBound; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(i);
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(i);
            sb.Append(" "); // if you don not want a trailing " " you need to check for the last iteration here
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
Using upperBoundFloor: 
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 
Using upperBoundCeil: 
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18
```

Comment: Thank you for you update. My length is 34 and expect output is 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17

Comment: Ok, so the fix is quite easy then. Divide the upper bound by two and use that as the limit. Only question then is what do you do if it's an odd number so e.g. 35, do you then output just up until 17 or 18?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a version for both scenarios

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to make function that will return sequence of your numbers, you can do it something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<int> GenerateRepeatedNumbers(int n)
    {
        bool again = true;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n)
        {
            if (again) {
                again = false;
                i += 1;
                yield return i;
            } 
            else {
                again = true;
                yield return i;
            }
        }
        
        if (i == n && !again)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 8;

        // In every iteration of for loop one of your numbers will be returned so you can do whatever you want with it
        foreach (int number in GenerateRepeatedNumbers(n))
        {
            Console.Write(number + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```